# Show that $\delta(G) = \Delta(G^c)$

Tags: graph-theory

So the following exercise is a proof:

$\text{Let } G \text{ a graph such that for } x \in V(G) \text{ } \delta_G(x) = \delta(G).\text{ Show that } \delta_{G^c}(x)=\Delta(G^c).$

**Proof**:
If $\delta_G(x) = \delta(G)$ we know that the neighborhood of the vertex $x$ is given with the minimum cardinality. So by definition of neighborhood: $$N_{G^c}(x)= \{y \in V(G) : xy \notin E(G)\}$$ Thus, the cardinality of this set must be de maximum. Therefore $\delta_{G^c}(x) = \Delta(G^c)_\square$.

I'm not sure if the argument of the neighborhood is valid, or I must to justify it. Either way, if there is a more convincing proof, i'd accept it.

Comment: What does $\delta_G(x)$ mean, and what does $G^c$ mean?

Comment: @bof $\delta_G(x)$ is the degree of the vertex $x$ under the graph $G$. $G^c$ is the complement of $G$

Comment: You need to precise your notation : usually $\delta$ is used for min degree, $d$ for degree, and $\Delta$ for max degree. Do you mean by 
$$ \forall x \in V(G), \delta_G(x)=\delta(G)$$
that your graph is regular? We would have
$$  \forall x \in V(G), \delta_G(x)=\delta(G)=\Delta(G)=r$$
And $G^c$ is $n-1-r$ regular, so that $\Delta(G^c)=n-1-r$

Comment: Let  $\delta_{G^c}(x) < \Delta(G^c)$                
$\exists y : \delta_{G^c}(x)< \delta_{G^c}(y)$ 
therefore $|V(G)|-1-\delta_{G}(x)< |V(G)|-1-\delta_{G}(y)\Rightarrow$ $\delta_{G}(x) > \delta_{G}(y)$ and it's contradiction!